# Robot Framework, Python, Selenium "Page Should Contain" do not work

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

Here is my code :

```
${verifications}              Create List
Set Test Variable             ${verifications}

Input text                    ${societes_input_nom}       ${nom_etablissement} ${TEST_NAME} 
Append To List                ${verifications}            ${nom_etablissement} ${TEST_NAME}

Input text                    ${societes_input_contact_email_casino}        ${email}
Append To List                ${verifications}          ${email}

Input text                    ${societes_input_contact_adresse}             ${adresse}
Append To List                ${verifications}       ${adresse}

Input text                    ${societes_input_site_web}                    ${url_siteweb}
Append To List                ${verifications}       ${url_siteweb}

FOR    ${item}    IN    @{verifications}
    Page Should Contain    ${item}
END
```

Here the HTML for the input :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="title"><h4>Nom de l'établissement
    </h4></label>
  <br>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon"  >
      <i class="fa fa-building">
      </i>
    </div>
    <input type="text" style="display: none;" id="initialvalue_prop_1" name="initialvalue_prop_1" maxlength="1000" value="TNR Activite Casino" 
           />
    <input type="text" id="prop_1" name="prop_1" maxlength="1000"  value="TNR Activite Casino" 
           />
```

But, the "page should Contain" do not find my ${nom_etablissement} ${TEST_NAME}
**But** when i'm looking the page, thoses words are in the page (and the DOM)

The error :

> Page should have contained text 'TNR Activite Casino' but did not.

I don't know how to fix that, I tried many thing but nothing work...

Can you help me pls ?

Comment: Please share the content of list `@{verifications}` and how html code looks like. Please dont share screenshot of code. Also please read [mcve] and follow that in all future posts. If  `Page should Contains` does not identify `${nom_etablissement}` what exception it throws?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the anwser, it's my first post here.
I have edited the orignal post !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Page Should Contain](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Page%20Should%20Contain) check for actual text and not the values of the attribute.  To get value of attribute you should use -

```
${Value}=   Get Element Attribute    xpath://input[@id='initialvalue_prop_1']     value
```

If you want to assert value inside the textfield then use the keyword -

```
Textfield Value Should Be    ${textfield_locator}   ${value_to_be_asserted}
```

For more details [Get Element Attribute](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Element%20Attribute)

Comment: I would mention that there is a `Get Value` keyword in SeleniumLibrary as well. But probably the OP would need the `Textfield Value Should Be` as this would assert the value, just like the `Page Should Contain` is an assert too.

Comment: @BenceKaulics,   yes, didn't realized that while posting the answer thanks for the hint. Updated the answer.

Comment: So i have to do ? 

-Input text                    ${societes_input_nom}                         ${nom_etablissement} ${TEST_NAME} 
    
    -${Value}=   Get Element Attribute     ${societes_input_nom}     value
    -Textfield Value Should Be     ${societes_input_nom}     ${Value}
    -Append To List                ${verifications}                              ${Value}
    -Set Test Variable             ${Value}

Comment: Depends what you want to do. If you want to assert the value inside textbox use `Textfield Value Should Be`. If you want to use the value of attribute then go for `Get Element Attribute`

Comment: I just want to check if my inputs are ok ! 
If the backoffice did its job

Comment: Either way should work then. I would prefer to assert it using locator only by creating dynamic locator which will have the data attribute or the 2nd option in the answer